# Comma punctuation

Tags: punctuation

The bold in the following sentence is where I am confused - is it punctuated properly?

> It will be necessary to either return this money to the government **if possible or, if not,** give it to the poor without the intention of gaining reward."

Answer (score 3):

It is. The commas in this passage serve to set off the appositive phrase, “if not.” For more information https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/appositives.html